# Does any dharma shastra not take reference to Manu/Kashyapa? Even by association

Tags: dharma-shastras, manu

One thing that always struck me as odd about the Parashara smriti is how often it references Manu. The Vishnu Smriti is said by Vishnu, but in response to a desire to know what Kashyapa (reincarnated Manu), also known as ​Ariṣṭanemi, says. Is any dharma shastra not dependent on him?

This is especially problematic as without speech marks it is really hard to tell how much is quoted.

Some are sneaky with the reference. The [Yājñavalkya Smṛti](https://archive.org/details/yajnavalkyasmrit00yj/page/4/mode/2up) happens in [Mithila](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/janaka), which was named after a king under Dasharatha (an incarnation of Manu). Thus, it seems all roads go to one end.

Even sneakier is the [Vyasa Smriti](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/books/ESSENCE-VEDA-VYASA-SMRITI.pdf). It makes it really hard to figure out which Vyasa is speaking. However, it does say his hermitage is in Varanasi and the [only person that seems to be referenced as having a hermitage at Varanasi is the sun, Mārtaṇḍa](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423784.html), [who is one of the Vyasas](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57102.html) (specifically the fifth of Vaivasvata Manvantara).

Now, the translation says he remembered from the heart, but the actual Sanskrit wording uses the word for an embryo. So more literally it means he remembered from when he was an embryo. Guess who his father is. It is Kashyapa, tying the Vyasa Smriti, as with all the others examined so far, to Manu/Kashyapa.

Now the [Apastamba Dharmasutra](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/apastamba-dharma-sutra/d/doc116233.html) (which I doubt as a real dharma shastra but I'll cover it anyway for its popularity) just gives its source as an undescriptive agreement of those who know the law. In the [Rig Veda](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv09114.htm), Kashyapa is described as knowing the law, so it could be him. It's kind of obvious from who they are that some of the authors know the correct law, but that is not the issue.

Comment: remove use of the term sneaky

Comment: @mar Do you have a better way to describe something so needlessly hard to track down? Well, without being more acussatory.

Comment: as is the case with all beginners who read shastras, their 'contradictions' are only apparent. there is already a resolution for every contradiction you have seen, and will see. until then, it is better to assume ignorance, and as a result, humility.

Comment: @mar This is not about contradictions, it is about the source. Although any apparent contradictions is odd when they all come from the same guy.

Comment: contradictions/misunderstandings are not at all odd for beginners reading english translations directly without a guru. why do you assume shastras must not quote Manu. Being the progenitor of manu-kind, and his smriti being the first one, naturally others will quote him if needed.

Comment: @mar How is the progenitor of mankind a good thing here? Sure he is superpowered and very intelligent, but he has the personality of humans in general, as all humans come from him. Have you seen the personality of humans in general?

Comment: you assume Manu is a normal human being like you and me. He is the manasika putra of Brahma himself. Manu is like a post. A manu can live/rule for an entire Manvantara which consists of 14 chaturyugas each of which is 43.2 lakh years in duration. When you see a man who can be created without physical union, and can live for 14*43 lakh years, then you can compare him to Manu.

Comment: @mar He is not normal. He is still human though and thus pretty much has to have the personality of a human. People with the personality of a human don't tend to be trustworthy no matter how powerful they are.

Comment: *"He is still human though"* - sure. a being created through manas by brahma, who can live for 14*43 lakh years is a "human". If he can be that far away from normal than you and me, he can also have a personality much farther away from normal than you and me.

Comment: @mar If you made the same thing true for a normal human, would you expect their nature to change on a fundamental level?

Comment: so, according to you, a person being born out of his father's manasika shakti instead of a physical union of man & woman is not a 'fundamental level' change, them living for 14*43 lakh years instead of 100 years is not a 'fundamental level' change, but somehow, a 'personality' that in normal humans changes quite often, and can be easily molded with guidance/therapy, is somehow a 'fundamental level' static universally constant item. sure. by that logic, Sri Rama was also a "man", so you will now assume he is also limited in the same way you are.

Comment: @mar Kali lives just as long and is implied to be born similarly as there is no reference to a womb or egg. He's definitely evil. https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/4/8/

Comment: so ? i didn't say long-life and non-physical creation are the CAUSE for a divine personality. several asuras share those traits but have evil personality. But you are stating that he is a "human", hence must have traits similar to humans.

Comment: @mar Exactly. He has similar (well he is human) traits as a human.

Comment: the point is YOU don't know what those traits are. if he is different in lifespan, he can be different in personality (or he could be same). If you are scientific & neutral/unbiased, you would say "i don't know which traits he shares with humans". **"well he is human"**. Finally, you don't actually know whether he is human

Comment: Hi @Aupakarana Abhibhaa , forgive me for my incomprehension, but I fail to understand your question. What is exactly that you ask or expect in the answer? Please explain, in simple language, a one-liner. :)

Answer (score 1):

Completing the explanations of dharma shastras/dharma sutras, for at least the ones that both [appear to be there completely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharma%C5%9B%C4%81stra) and are in the [Padma Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc365820.html) canon, is the explanation of the Vāsiṣṭha Smriti/Dharma Sutra. It conveniently just tells you it's from Manu.

> 17. Manu has declared that the (peculiar) laws of countries, castes, and families (may be followed) in the absence of (rules of) the revealed texts.